# Download iOS app from iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

Hi I need to try an iOS app that is in the app store. I don't have any device so i was wondering if i could download it from the iOS Simulator.
Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Applications on App Store are compiled for arm architecture, while the simulator runs apps for i386.

Comment: Aww damnit, you beat me by 10 seconds. +1

Comment: Thanks i have no choice than looking for a device